# JQuery highlight effect changes to different colors which are permanent when buttons are pressed rapidly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on a rock paper scissors game in javascript and I implemented a color indicator after choosing one of the options, but the colors change and are permanent instead of fading after the intended time if you press the buttons rapidly.

This is the code I use to change the color:

```
$("#score").stop();
$("#score").effect("highlight", {color: "green"}, 500);
```

Here's a jsfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/DXvSG/2/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$("#score").stop(true, true);
```

This clears the animation queue and makes the current animation jump to the end of its timeline, thus "clearing the way" for a new one.

Also, note that you can chain the `stop` and `effect` methods, like so:

```
$("#score").stop(true, true).effect("highlight", ...
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DXvSG/3

Comment: Aha! Thanks, I knew it would be something simple